# How can I get a vertical list to load PDF's into an iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, onclick, setattribute

I'm trying to get this vertical list to load the document titles I put inside the Load_content() during an Onclick event. The satisfactory outcome will be that everytime I click a new link... a new PDF loads into the iframe

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Literature of Andrew Willis
    </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css" type="text/css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cssverticalmenu.css" />


    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function load_content (link) {
    document.getElementById("iframe").setAttribute("src","link" );
    }

    </script>

</head>
<body>


    <div id="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="mainlogo.jpg" height=100 width=400></a>
    </div>


    <div id="content">

        <div id="leftcolumn">

             <ul class="glossymenu">  
                <li><a href="#" onclick="load_content(Look at me now.pdf)">Short Essays</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="load_content(hangmansdog.pdf)" >Poetry</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="http://www.pourinpourout.com" >Blog</a></li>  
            </ul>
        </div> 
        <div id="rightcolumn">
            <div id="content">
            <iframe id="iframe1" src="#"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few typos in your code.  You gave your iframe an id of "iframe1" but referenced it in your JS using "iframe".  You also shouldn't have quotes around link because you are using it as a variable, line 13 should look like this:

```
document.getElementById("iframe1").setAttribute("src",link );
```

You will however, probably want to put single quotes around the links themselves when you go to link them. i.e. `onclick="load_content('Look at me now.pdf')"`